# Ошибка в DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, office

Выдаёт ошибку в `DataContext` что в `xmlns:onf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;assembly=Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote` не существует `OneNoteHierarchy.Current`.

Код ниже. Что не так?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:onf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;assembly=Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/Page16.PNG" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SectionTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PageTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/Section16.PNG" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NotebookTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/Book16.PNG" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView Name="NotebookTree" BorderThickness="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Notebooks}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NotebookTemplate}"
              DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static onf:OneNoteHierarchy.Current}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил оказалось забыл подключить библиотеки OneNoteFramework.dll и OneNoteCore.dll

Comment: Откуда скачивали библиотеки OneNoteFramework.dll и OneNoteCore.dll?

Answer (score 0):

А у вас референс на эту библиотеку в проекте присутствует? Может, вам их просто через NuGet установить нужно?